# Wygwam fields (in Matrix) not initialized when switching fields with Entry Type

Tags: matrix, wygwam

I'm using Entry Type to hide/show fields. If the field is a Matrix with Wygwam columns, the Wygwam fields don't initialize when the Matrix field is revealed by Entry Type. However, if I reload the Edit page, Wygwam intializes and all is well. Will be irritating to client to have to reload page for Wygwam's buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the "Defer CKEditor initialization?" feature in the Wygwam celltype settings. This will prevent Wygwam from initializing until the client clicks on the field.

Comment: This doesn't work. If you use 'defer initialisation', the field doesn't initialise when you click on it either. This same problem also applies to Assets, Date fields, basically any field type that uses javascript...